# How to send the value another server?

Tags: php

How to send the value another server (not my server) in PHP? I used to curl PHP but it didn't work.

Comment: First of all, welcome to stack overflow!  Secondly,click could you please add more information about what you are tying to do? Maybe add some code you tried too, it will help people to answer your question.

Comment: sorry idk what you mean.. you have confused me

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just edit your question and add the relevant parts of your code into it. You need to show your own efforts, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are trying to send data to another server. Is that server CORS enabled and you are authorized to send data to that server?

Steps you can take to debug this:

1. Check if the target server allows such requests.
2. Check the URL you are trying to curl
3. Check the data format i.e., Content-Type

In future try adding more information and code snippets.

Comment: But curl connect web site and get hidden value,but curl post no send